# Best design to pass parameters between beans with JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

I've been reading about different ways to pass parameters between beans with JSF 2 and I don't really know which one would be the best for this scenario.

Let's say I have a process with 6-7 views, and each one has a "go back" button to return to the previous view where I want to recover the data it had.

One option would be to use a session bean where we store all the data, but I cannot do it because we have too many different processes.

I would like to have 1 bean per view, so I don't have every single process in one single view bean.

Some views have too much data to recover when we return to them, so I don't want to send them as request params, the url would be too long.

What else could we do using JSF2? We use Omnifaces and Primefaces too.

Example of views/beans.

- ViewA with 20 inputFields / BeanA to search in the database with the
  input data from ViewA and show the results in a table in ViewA.
- ViewB to access to the details from one of the results selected in ViewA / BeanB to format/process the details selected.
- ViewC with a form to edit some of the details / BeanC to manage the details
- ViewD with a history of the modifications / BeanD to manage the history.

Each View has a button to return to the previous one ViewD -> ViewC -> ViewB -> ViewA.

Thanks.

Comment: The first part smells a lot like a "flow" (JSF2.2) If you can switch, one option would be create the flow, create a flowScoped bean, and that bean to handle the `beanA`, `beanB`... If you may upgrade to JSF2.2, I will write this as an answer. https://blog.oio.de/2014/02/12/a-comprehensive-example-of-jsf-faces-flow/

Comment: This is a really broad/opinion-based question, but apart from the new Flows in JSF, a combination of the View and Flash scopes will also work here. Upgrading to v-2.2 just for JSF Flows (which is not entirely smooth yet) feels like overkill to me

Comment: @SJuan76 I've been reading the blog you suggested and it looks like a great solution. I'm going to upgrade first to JSF 2.2 and test it right away. Thanks. If I solve the problem I will post back with the choisen answer.

Answer (score 0):

The codi ViewAccessScope sounds like a perfect fit here. As soon as a bean is not referenced in a (new) view, it gets destroyed